# How do I move to the next/previous number

Tags: cursor-movement, cursor-motions, ideavim

How do I move the cursor to the next/previous number?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> can't be used since I have `:set nrformats+=alpha`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next number: `/[0-9]` or `/\d`

Previous number: `?[0-9]` or `?\d`

For non-decimal numbers, you can also use these equivalences:

```
\d : [0-9]        -> decimal digit
\x : [0-9A-Fa-f]  -> hex digit
\o : [0-7]        -> octal digit
```

Comment: Slightly faster, perhaps, and more flexible: `/\d` and `?\d`

Comment: Significantly slower, indubitably, and less flexible ;)  `/[[:digit:]]` and `?[[:digit:]]`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble added, thanks